# Convert multiple element list into array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following list

```
['0, 0, 0.16548735788092,\n',
 '1, 3.90625E-05, 0.368149412097409,\n',
 '2, 7.8125E-05, 0.184674297925085,\n',
 '3, 0.0001171875, 0.00359755125828087,\n',
 '4, 0.00015625, 0.0131910212803632,\n',
 '5, 0.0001953125, 0.24703185306862,\n',
 '6, 0.000234375, 0.474876766093075,\n',]
```

BWhich I obtained from

```
data = f.readlines()
```

I would like to transform this list into an array with 3 columns. Thanks

Comment: you need show what you have try.

Comment: You can get the first element of that array, split by `\n` and then split by `,`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way. Input list is `lst`. The output is a list of 3 tuples (one for each column). I've also converted the numbers into `float` and removed `\n`.

```
cols = list(zip(*(map(float, i.replace('\n', '').split(',')[:-1]) for i in lst)))
```

Answer (score 2):

We iterate per line. Then for each line we split on the `,` and assign the respective values to temporary values and then add a column with three entries to the array

```
array=[]
for line in f.readlines():
    a_0,a_1,a_2,_=line.split(",")
    array.append([a_0,a_1,a_2])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[list(map(float, i.strip().split(',')[:-1])) for i in mylist]
```

Output:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.16548735788092],
 [1.0, 3.90625e-05, 0.368149412097409],
 [2.0, 7.8125e-05, 0.184674297925085],
 [3.0, 0.0001171875, 0.00359755125828087],
 [4.0, 0.00015625, 0.0131910212803632],
 [5.0, 0.0001953125, 0.24703185306862],
 [6.0, 0.000234375, 0.474876766093075]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your list as a number, here you go:

```
list_3d = []

for line in data:
    columns = list(map(float, line.replace(' ','').split(',')[:-1]))
    list_3d.append(columns)

print(list_3d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
data=['0, 0, 0.16548735788092,\n',
 '1, 3.90625E-05, 0.368149412097409,\n',
 '2, 7.8125E-05, 0.184674297925085,\n',
 '3, 0.0001171875, 0.00359755125828087,\n',
 '4, 0.00015625, 0.0131910212803632,\n',
 '5, 0.0001953125, 0.24703185306862,\n',
 '6, 0.000234375, 0.474876766093075,\n',]



print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(float,x.split(',')[:-1])),data)))
```

output:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.16548735788092], [1.0, 3.90625e-05, 0.368149412097409], [2.0, 7.8125e-05, 0.184674297925085], [3.0, 0.0001171875, 0.00359755125828087], [4.0, 0.00015625, 0.0131910212803632], [5.0, 0.0001953125, 0.24703185306862], [6.0, 0.000234375, 0.474876766093075]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string.split](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), using `', '` as the delimiter.

```
new_list = []

for line in data:
    line = line.strip()      # get rid of \n
    line = line.strip(',')   # get rid of trailing comma
    line = line.split(', ')  # split into items
    new_list.append(line)    # add to the new list
```

The output is then:

```
[['0', '0', '0.16548735788092'],
 ['1', '3.90625E-05', '0.368149412097409'],
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As I Understand from  the question , there is need of 2D of (mx3) array, that stores each element of the data variable.

```
#creating 2-D Matrix 
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(0,3)] for y in range(0,len(data))]
    for x in data :
        a1=x.split(",") #split each element
        for i in range(0,len(data)):
            for j in range(0,3): #removes inserting \n
                  Matrix[i][j]=a1[j] 
print(Matrix)
```